# What is the emf in this circuit?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction

There is an infinite solenoid with radius $r$ inside the first loop powered by a current that changes over time so that the magnitude of the magnetic field inside the solenoid is $B(t)$. According to Faraday's law this generates an emf in the circuit, given by:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}=-\frac{d\Phi}{dt}=-\pi r^2\frac{dB}{dt}
\end{equation}

[image: The circuit]

This is equivalent to an emf generator. My guess is that the correct configuration is
[image: My guess]

where the cell provides an emf $\mathcal{E}$ as above. In a book I have, though, the solenoid is considered equivalent to the following configuration:

[image: Book configuration]

Where each cell provides an emf $\mathcal{E}'=\frac{\mathcal{E}}{4}$. This situation is clearly different and yields different results for the currents running in the loops. Actually, the left loop is no different mathematically, while the second loop is because of the generator in the common branch.

What is the correct configuration and why?

I thought that Faraday law should apply both to the left loop and to the big loop including the right and the left loop, this is why the first configuration looks fine to me.

EDIT: here is the figure in the textbook (readcomments in the accepted answer for more information). Sorry for the quality.

[image]

Comment: Strictly speaking this situation violates the basic assumptions of circuit theory. The strictly correct approach is to not use circuit theory where it does not apply.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is violated?

Comment: See here: https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/circuit-analysis-assumptions/ This scenario violates the 1st assumption

Comment: If you ignore the changing magnetic fields that's the case, but as soon as you consider the induced emf you should be fine.

Comment: no, you are going to get into trouble using a theory when its foundational assumptions are strongly violated. I don’t know of a published self-consistent circuit theory where the first assumption is relaxed, do you? Simply assuming that everything “should be fine” is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The emf is present in the left hand loop and the outer loop, because the changing flux is linked with both these loops. There is no net emf in the right hand loop, because no (changing) flux is linked with it.

It is therefore fine, for purposes of circuit theory, to represent the emf as if it were concentrated in the place you have shown (or in the left hand vertical line of the circuit or the left hand of the bottom line).

[We can understand where the textbook writers were coming from. They see the left hand loop surrounding the solenoid and believe that there ought to be emfs in all four sides of the square, including in the wire containing R2. They are forgetting that, applying the same reasoning to the outer loop, there ought also to be a 'downward' emf in R3, as well as emfs in other parts of the loop. So the emf they have shown in the wire containing R2 is not, on this viewpoint, the only emf in the right hand loop – and *we* know that the *resultant* emf in the right hand loop is zero. **In general it is unsafe to argue in terms of emfs other than *resultant* emfs in loops.**]

Which book gave you the other answer?

Comment: It is not a famous textbook. It was written by some professors in my university (italy)

Comment: The textbook actually had another solenoid in the right loop and considered that equivalent to 4 generators as well (so 8 generators in total), but conceptually it was the same thing as above. Quite relieving to know my guess was correct, since otherwise the emf in the outer loop wouldn't agree with Faraday's law.

Comment: Thank you. Mistakes in textbooks can provide a valuable service, by stimulating thought – just as long as there are not too many mistakes!

Comment: I've added to my answer, but have not considered the two-solenoid set-up mentioned In your comment.

Comment: For the sake of completeness I added to my post the figure in the book.